# Code Optimization Tips:

Tags: sorting, assembly, masm, masm32

I am using the following ASM routine to bubble sort an array. I want to know of the inefficiencies of my code:

```
.386
.model flat, c
option casemap:none


.code
            public sample
            sample PROC
            ;[ebp+0Ch]Length
            ;[ebp+08h]Array
                            push ebp
                            mov ebp, esp
                            push ecx
                            push edx
                            push esi
                            push eax
                            mov ecx,[ebp+0Ch]
                            mov esi,[ebp+08h]
                _bubbleSort:
                            push ecx
                            push esi
                            cmp ecx,1
                            je _exitLoop
                            sub ecx,01h
                            _miniLoop:
                                        push ecx
                                        mov edx,DWORD PTR [esi+4]
                                        cmp DWORD PTR [esi],edx
                                        ja _swap
                                        jmp _continueLoop
                            _swap:      
                                        lodsd
                                        mov DWORD PTR [esi-4],edx
                                        xchg DWORD PTR [esi],eax    
                                        jmp _skipIncrementESI
                            _continueLoop:
                                        add esi,4
                            _skipIncrementESI:
                                        pop ecx
                                        loop _miniLoop 
                            _exitLoop:
                            pop esi
                            pop ecx 
                            loop _bubbleSort
                            pop eax
                            pop esi
                            pop edx
                            pop ecx
                            pop ebp
                            ret 
            sample ENDP
            END
```

Basically I have two loops, as usual for the bubble sort algorithm. The value of ecx for the outer loop is 10, and for the inner loop it is [ecx-1]. I have tried the routine and it compiles and runs successfully, but I am not sure if it is efficient.

Comment: You do realize that bubble sort is a terrible sorting algorithm in terms of efficiency? What is the point (other than to provide an example of what **not** to do) of digging down to the assembler level if you are going to employ a quadratic-time sorting algorithm?

Comment: Any other inefficiency *pales* next to the simple fact that you're using a bubblesort. Implementing a bubblesort in assembly is (quite rightly) the canonical example of doing entirely the wrong things and wasting your time on micro-optimizing the wrong algorithm.

Comment: I literally LOLed when I read that you implemented a bubble sort in assembly.

Comment: okay guys, I know that bubble sort is not efficient. I am not speaking about the algorithm. I am asking you if I am coding ASM in an efficient manner. I am learning assembly right now, not working on some project. I am just asking for tips on the usage of registers and stuff. I repeat, this is not about the bubble sort algorithm. Thanks for the responses anyway!

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. Crowdsourcing an optimizing compiler for one person's assembly code is not an activity of general interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several simple tips:

1) Try to minimize the number of conditional jumps, because they are very expensive. Unroll if possible. 
2) Reorder instructions to minimize stalls because of data depencency:

```
cmp DWORD PTR [esi],edx ;// takes some time to compute,
mov edx,DWORD PTR [esi+4] ; 
ja _swap ;// waits for results of cmp
```

3) Avoid old composite instructions (`dec`, `jnz` pair is faster than `loop` and is not bound to `ecx` register)

It would be quite difficult to write assembly code that is faster than the code generated by optimizing C compiler, because you should consider lots of factors: size of data and instruction caches, alignments, pipeline, instruction timings. You can find some good documentation about this [here](http://agner.org/optimize/). I especially recommend the first book: *Optimizing software in C++*

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do to speed up your assembly code:

- don't do things like `ja label_1 ; jmp label_2`. Just do `jbe label_2` instead.
- `loop` is a very slow instruction. `dec ebx; jnz loopstart` is much faster
- use all registers instead of repeatedly push/pop ecx and esi. Use `ebx` and `edi` too.
- jmp-targets should be well aligned. Use `align 4` before the two loop-starts and after the `jbe`

Get yourself a manual for your cpu from Intel (you can download it as pdf), it has the timings for the opcodes, maybe it has other hints too.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute for "add esi,4" if we do not need a flag for this instruction:

```
_continueLoop:
            lea esi,[esi+4]
```